# TypeError: bad operand type for unary +: 'str' when I try to build an XML and store it in a variable

Tags: python, string

I have a string that will use as XML here is the string wich when I try to print it gives me the error in the title:

```
xml = "<header xmlns=\"mfp:anaf:dgti:spv:reqUploadFisier:v1\"\n"
+ " xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">\n"
+ "    <upload fisier=\"" + "123" + "\"/>\n"
+ "</header>"
```

I would like to print the string. Why does it give me this error?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you use parentheses, brackets, braces or a backslash, Python lines end with the newline character. The following text is three separate lines that show the same error:

```
str_ = "A"
+ "B"
+ "C"
```

You can extend lines using a backslash:

```
str_ = "A" \
+ "B" \
+ "C"
```

You can also group with parentheses:

```
str_ = ("A"
+ "B"
+ "C")
```

If all the components of the string are literals, you don't even need the `+` operator: neighboring string literals are concatenated automatically:

```
str_ = ("A"
"B"
"C")
```

Another way to concatenate strings is interpolation. This is generally useful when your components are variables of arbitrary type. You can do something like

```
a = "A"
b = "B"
c = "C"
str_ = f'{a}{b}{c}'
```